# Can 'Trust' be quantified?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, terminology

I believe the concept of trust or the word `trust` itself can be given many definitions depending on someone's understanding of it.

Agreeing with the definition given on dictionnary.com website as *`confidence` or `reliance` on the integrity, strength, ability, surety, of a person or thing*; can we expect that this `reliance/confidence` be diminished or increased?

I've heard many people (even myself sometimes) referring to trust as something we can manipulate quantitatively in a way that it can be considered decreased on someone and/or increased on someone else. How can we measure how much we trust someone? Isn't reducing `trust` the absence of `trust` itself? Isn't increasing `trust` the presence of `trust` itself? If not, how can we consider the `trust` increased or decreased? How little can it be to be `no trust` and how much can it be to be `trust` or `too much trust`? How shall we define a concept of `no trust` if it happens to be diminished at that level? Isn't that an instance of `Void` or would it still be an instance of `trust` in a way that it is empty quantitatively?

If `trust` can be reduced or increased how can we then call that `half-trust`? wouldn't that be relying and not-relying at the same time? or having confidence and not having confidence on the same `object`* at the same time?

Is it a human common mistake to consider `trust` quantitatively manipulable or is it how I see it that confuses me?

Thank you so much for your opinions.

Note: Object here refers to an instance of a person or something.

Comment: You either trust or you don't, there is no decreasing or increasing of trust on a scale as you alluded to.
However, when you speak of trust, its the persons actions that you apply trust or no trust to. 
For instance, you might know someone who lies a lot about a whole range of things but, if you know this person does not have the capacity to kill someone, then you could say that you don't trust a word they say BUT you trust that they would never smother you in your sleep. That is an extreme example but it demonstrates my point.

Comment: Like most things, trust is a matter of degree.  If you trust someone a lot, then you think the probability they would harm or betray you is very low.  If you trust someone not at all, then you think the probability they would harm or betray you is high if they are given the opportunity.  This probability of betrayal can be any number between 0 and 1, and so trust is on a sliding scale as well.

Comment: I trust you enough to lend you $5 but not $10 is as much about my trust as it is about my valuing the $. Say I can lose 5 without a thought, yet 10 would cause me trouble. Now a bank makes a different calculation of trust when you go for a loan.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't reducing trust the absence of trust itself?

One useful way to understand the concept of trust is to see it as having additional predicate places.

I trust my dentist to look at my teeth and advise me if there are any cavaties, and to be able to provide repair work to help them last longer; I wouldn't necessarily trust my dentist to look after my pet cat.

Having signed a contract with my place of work, I trust that they will pay me at the end of the month.  I didn't trust them to do that before I started working for them and we made that agreement.

After having moved out, I generally trust that my parents will respect my independence.  However, if they find themselves in medical need, they may want to contact me to ask for help.  I might revise my expectations of that relationship in response to a change in circumstances - they are in need, and I want to help, but if I accept (and I will), my support may impact that degree of independence.

So understanding that our concept of trust should, if it is healthy, be responsive to circumstances, we can also make sense of an initial quantitative notion of trust as an epistemological measure.  Specifically, if I am facing some degree of uncertainty as to the state of the world, then that same degree of uncertainty will carry over to the proportion of the time when someone is likely to be in a position where I could (depending on how I come to trust someone) trust them, at that time, to do something.

If you are a determinist about human behaviour, this is actually all you need, because a person's environment (conceived across time) serves as the input to their brain and body's functions that generate their behaviour.  However, this function is of course hugely complex, and we are unlikely to have access to its exact metaphysical change value.  So, we as epistemological agents need to estimate it by asking relevant questions, both of them and of the world in general.

Can I reasonably expect that someone will respond a given way all of the time?  Well, what I can do is revise my estimates of how likely they are to do so in response to evidence that I have about how they (in particular and as a person in general) act in this kind of situation right now.  Bayesians will say that the best way to do this is by following the rules of probabilistic reasoning and updating beliefs to retain some degree of consistency in our various beliefs about the world, which is why you get particular formulations of the "probability" that someone will do a particular thing.

But really, I think the key insight is the first one, more than the numbers themselves.  Trust isn't an all-or-nothing thing, and a recognition of the complexities of the human condition go a long way towards making more useful choices about who, how and to what degree to trust those around us to act in various ways.